# From python numpy array or list to COM SAFEARRAY

Tags: python, win32com, xlwings, pythoncom

Is there any built in method or any other way to translate a python numpy array/list to COM SAFEARRAY?

There is a similar method in R:
[R Matrix to COMSAFEARRAY](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/rdrr.io/a/github/omegahat/RDCOMClient/man/asCOMArray.html)

Quite weirdly I have not found anything in python.

I want to use it in order to pass an array into a VBA function which I call from python.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xlwings takes care of this:

```py
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np

book = xw.Book()
book.sheets[0]['A1'].value = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

Comment: Well yes in that case it’s ok. BUT, when I am trying to pass a list in a macro which has a VBA function which accept something as variant, I get an error saying TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be sequences (of sequences) or a buffer object. Any workaround?

Comment: In addition Felix, how can optional parameters in a VBA function be treated when calling it from python? I have not seen anything in the documentation

Comment: I think it makes more sense to ask these questions in GitHub issues, if you don't mind.